Does the subject order matter in a comparison?
Given the two sentences

"I think you are more bothered by small annoyances than I am."
"I think I am less bothered by small annoyances than you are."

Both are saying essentially the same thing: one person is more bothered and the other is less bothered by small annoyances.
Does the first carry a connotation that the listener is being more criticized than the second?

I think it depends more on whose personality/behaviour is being discussed.  A: "I would have complained about X." B: "Well, I think you are more bothered by small annoyances than I am."

Not really a lot of information here to go on. It would depend on a lot of factors. It could be boastful, critical, teasing, sympathetic, or a non-sequitur.

"Carry a connotation?" No, that's asking too much. Have a subtle psychological impact? Maybe, maybe.
Whether we compare apples against oranges or oranges against apples, the differences between them are the same. So whether we say that the orange's skin is thicker and rougher, or the apple's skin is thinner and smoother, we're making the same observation. Both explicit and implicit payloads of meaning are the same. The impact of the statement might depend on the culture of the fruit basket, and how they feel about being called rough or smooth.
A more significant impact is that, as we flip the sentence order, either the apple or the orange becomes the subject of the sentence, and therefore the focus of attention. This is easy to see in the second person:

Billy, you're shorter than Jimmy!
Jimmy, you're taller than Billy!

The boys' feelings may depend on whether it's desirable to be taller or shorter, so the extra attention may be positive or negative, but whoever takes the subject role takes a bit more of the spotlight.
But again, this isn't a "connotation" so much as a consequence.


Does the first carry a connotation that the listener is being more criticized than the second?

No. The nuance of the statement, in either form, is entirely dependent upon context: both are neutral.

Yes, there is a connotation of criticism, at least in today's speech.  If the "I think" is dropped from these statements, then the second statement becomes an "I" statement suggesting that the speaker is talking about themself.  People are trained to use "I" statements in effective oral communication because it is less confrontational than a "you" statement that may elicit a defensive reaction from the listener. By using a "you" statement the speaker not only projects a criticism but also suggests they don't care if it upsets the listener.  Improved communication through use of "I" statements isn't just a psychological parlor trick; there are strong and universal reactions to how these statements are received, so the connotation is definitely there.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
